# Update Listboxes based on Ajax result with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting my 2 listboxes to work as I need them. I'm using asp.net MVC5. I have 2 multiselect Listboxes (and a few other controls) on a Modal form.

Listbox1 contains a number of Items that are available to be selected, the user selects one or more items in the list and clicks a button to "move" them to the Listbox2.

On the button click, I submit the entire form via Ajax and I "move" the items in the method. Now Listbox2 should contain the items the user selected, and the Listbox1 should be left with the items the user did not select.

The method is fine as I can move the data in the database, my issue is how to get the Listboxes to show the correct data afterwards.

These are the model properties I have to feed the listboxes :-

```
List<Int64> List1 
List<SelectListItem> List1Items

List<Int64> List2 
List<SelectListItem> List2Items
```

In each case there is a list to hold the selected items and a list for the ListBoxFor display.

The Listboxes are set up as follows :-

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(i => Model.List1, Model.List1Items)
@Html.ListBoxFor(i => Model.List2, Model.List2Items)
```

I noticed that when I submit the form, List1Items and List2Items do not get passed to the controller. That's not a big deal as I can sort those out in the method and pass them back in.

I basically need to know how to update the 2 listboxes using jquery when the model is passed back to the Ajax function, which is below :-

```
$.ajax
({
    url: '@Url.Action("MoveItems", "MyController")',
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: $("#MyForm").serialize(),
    success: function (retValue) {
        if (retValue.Result === "Success") {

            // What do I need here ?
            // Model is passed back as 'retValue.Data'

            alert(retValue.SuccessMessage);
        }
        else if (retValue.Result === "Error") {
             alert(retValue.ErrorMessage);
        }
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert('Unknown Server Error');
    }
});
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below one.

```
<script>
  var lst1 = $("[id*=List1]");
  lst1.empty();
  $.each(retValue.Data, function () 
  {
     lst1.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, got the following error with your example :-   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Text': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: Please use of listbox id, and then check

Comment: please check text field and value field inside retValue.Data, according to it write keys in jqeury.